# How to hook SBWiFiManager into an app

Tags: objective-c, ios7, hook, wifimanager, theos

I would like to know how can I hook `SBWiFiManager` methods into an app that I'm making with "theos".

I know that "SBWiFiManager" is a class that only exist in `SpringBoard`, and I know how to hook that making a tweak but not how to do that making an app.

I just want an app for my purpose with a switch to turn on/off the "wifi" connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hook a class from another process. As you said, `SBWiFiManager` only exists in `SpringBoard`. What you can do, however is work with any of the existing methods for IPC, probably Darwin notifications as your aim is to switch the connection. Take a look at CoreFoundation's Notification Center API, where you will be using `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification()` in your application and `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver()` in a tweak injected into SpringBoard.